# Moving Array Values Down 1

Tags: c++

Given an integer value indicating the row number of the record (starting from 0 
ending at current size ­ 1), delete the student record, move up all the following record one 
row up in the spreadsheet. If the user entered an integer out of bound (<0 or >= size), 
prompt “No such row. Can not drop row ??.” Replace ?? with the row number.

Ime not sure whats wrong with the code. It wont move the array information about it down 1;

```
void drop(string names[], int sections[], int grades[], int size){
    int i;
    int drop;
    cin >> drop;
    if (drop > size){
        cout << "No such row. Can not drop row" << drop << " /n";

    }else{
        for (i = 0; i <= drop; i++){
            if (i == drop){
                names[drop] = {""};
                sections[drop] = {};
                grades[drop] = {};
                for (i = drop; drop < size-1; i++){
                    names[i] = names[i + 1];
                    sections[i] = sections[i + 1];
                    grades[i] = grades[i + 1];
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void drop(string names[], int sections[], int grades[], int size){
    int i;
    int drop;
    cin >> drop;
    if (drop >= size){        //NOTE: >=, not >
        cout << "No such row. Can not drop row" << drop << " /n";
        return;
    }
    for(i=drop; i<size-1; i++)
        names[i] = names[i + 1];
        sections[i] = sections[i + 1];
        grades[i] = grades[i + 1];
    }
}
```

}

Of course, if you want to change the size of the arrays, it would be better to use vectors.

However, you cannot do the following, since name_of_array[drop] is an *element* in the array, and not an array within the array. In either case, this is illegal code.

```
names[drop] = {""};       //should be names[drop] = "";
sections[drop] = {};      // ''    '' sections[drop] = 0;
grades[drop] = {};        // ''    '' grades[drop] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
            for (i = drop; drop < size-1; i++){
```

to

```
            for (i = drop; i < size-1; i++){
```

The code under the `else` block can be simplified further to:

```
           for (i = drop; i < size-1; i++){
                names[i] = names[i + 1];
                sections[i] = sections[i + 1];
                grades[i] = grades[i + 1];
            }
```

You don't need the lines prior to that.

Answer (score 0):

How do you feel about using standard library algorithms? You could use the following instead of raw loops:

```
void drop(string names[], int sections[], int grades[], int size) {
    int drop;
    cin >> drop;
    if (drop >= size) {
        cout << "No such row. Can not drop row" << drop << " \n";
    } else {
        std::move(   &names[drop + 1],    &names[size],    &names[drop]);
        std::move(&sections[drop + 1], &sections[size], &sections[drop]);
        std::move(  &grades[drop + 1],   &grades[size],   &grades[drop]);
    }
}
```

If your compiler doesn't support C++11 just change `std::move` to `std::copy` in the above code.